# Create table under schema using java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

how to create a user in SQL, I am unable to do and still using "sys as dba" for connections and the password i created when installed.
Also I create a schema named USER using DBeaver in oracle. but when I am creating a table in java with

```
final String newTable = "CREATE TABLE USER.Employee"+
                                "(empId NUMBER NOT NULL,"+
                                "name varchar2(10) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                                "PRIMARY KEY (empId))";
```

its not working. its giving error-
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1036)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1845)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1810)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:294)
at com.sumit.batch.BatchEntry.main(BatchEntry.java:19)
```

please help..:)

Comment: Create a regular user. Connect as that user, then you don't need the `USER` prefix in your DDL

Answer (score 1):

Use PreparedStatement to create a table.

### Sample:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("create table survey (id int, name VARCHAR(30) );");

pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

### Resource Link:

1. [JDBC PreparedStatement example – Create a table](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-create-a-table/)
2. [Create a Table Using PreparedStatement : Preparedstatement «
   Database « Java Tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/CreateaTableUsingPreparedStatement.htm)

### UPDATE for another issue:

### Issue:

> SQL Error [942] [42000]: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

### Resolution:

**Configuring Oracle**

Ensure that you have a database instance available for Bamboo (either create a new one or use an existing one).

Within that database instance, create a user which Bamboo will connect as (e.g. bamboo-user). (tick) Remember this database user name, as it will be used to configure Bamboo's connection to this database.
(info) When you create a user in Oracle, Oracle will create a 'schema' automatically.

```
create user bamboo-user identified by password;
```

Ensure that the user has the following permissions:

```
grant connect, resource, create table to bamboo-user;
```

For more, you can go through this 2 links:

1. [java.sql.SQLException ORA-00942 table or view does not exist](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-221446320.html)
2. [Configuring Oracle](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/oracle-289276820.html)

Comment: I wan to create the table in that particular schema how would I do it in java? I removed the schema.table_name I am able to create the table.   But when I do select statement in sql `select * from employee` it says `SQL Error [942] [42000]: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
` I dont know where the table is created too. I am using DBeaver for SQL

Comment: Got it for the new user.. Thank you.. Still in confusion for the table though. Where the table goes in which schema...? if I just do a create table and not doing schema.table_name